# Finding a text from single or multiple Mysql databases using a query

Tags: mysql, database, search, full-text-search

Is there any way to find a text from single or multiple databases using a mysql query.
**Note:** i know  the database can be downloaded into a file and searched but i want to know if its possible using a mysql query

Comment: Are you trying to search for a value in all fields in a database?

Comment: Do you mean multiple databases, or multiple tables within a database? Please provide more information about the structure of your data and where you're searching.

Comment: @Tom Ys i am try to find a value or a string in all fields of a database

Comment: @Barmar there are multiple tables in a database and such multiple databases also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do it other than a UNION of lots of SELECT statements that check each column in each table in each database.

```
SELECT col1
FROM db1.table1
WHERE col1 LIKE '%text%'

UNION ALL

SELECT col2
FROM db1.table1
WHERE col2 LIKE '%text%'

UNION ALL

SELECT col1
from db1.table2
WHERE col1 LIKE '%text%'

UNION ALL

select col1
from db2.table1
WHERE col1 LIKE '%text%'

and so on
```

Comment: Though not a perfect way of doing this but still a way to do this.....